# How to run composer.phar in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing problem while installing the Laravel framework, actually while installing I am getting this type of error in small window.

```
Setup cannot continue because the following applications are using files that need to be updated

 It is showing Windows Explorer is running
```

I am not using window explorer even that was not running

Please anyone help me

Comment: restart your computer

Comment: @maytham yes i am working in windows environment

Comment: @maytham thanks.....i have fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just run `C:\path\to\php.exe composer.phar`
How you install composer? Installer or manual?

Comment: Actually while i am installing getting the above small window with error message

Comment: Have You try install with Admin Privilege ? Try install composer manually. Download phar package and run as I said in prev post